# Prove following equation is an identity problem: $(1+ \cot x)^2 - 2\cot x = 1/((1-\cos x )(1+\cos x ))$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to 'prove' that $$(1+ \cot(x))^2 - 2\cot(x) = \frac1{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))}$$

The book doesn't actually show answers for these types of problems, which hasn't been a problem till now, I've found the ones for far easy enough, but this one is stumping me. I know the $1 + \cot$ can be changed to csc, and got the right hand side down to $1/\sin^2$, but past that I'm stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction of what to do next? Or what I should have done if I'm way off with what I've done so far?

Comment: Yea, I messed up, it should be $(1+ cot(x))^2 for the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
(1 + \cot x)^2 - 2\cot x &= \frac 1 {(1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)} \\
1+2\cot x+\cot^2x-2\cot x&=\frac 1{1-\cos x+\cos x-\cos^2x} \\
1 + \left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)^2&=\frac 1{1-\cos^2x} \\
\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}&=\frac 1{\sin^2 x} \\
\frac{1}{\sin^2x}&=\frac 1{\sin^2 x}
\end{align}
$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: Wait, how do you get from line 3 to line 4 on the left side?

Comment: @windy401 $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ $\implies\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\cos^2x=1-\cos^2x$ $\implies\sin^2x=1-{\cos}^2x$

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it because it's wrong. E.g., for $x=\pi/4$ the left-hand side is zero while the right-hand side goes to infinity.

Comment: I messed up, it should be $(1+ cot(x))^2 for the left side.

Comment: @windy401: Still doesn't work out.

Comment: Wow I am so sorry, it's cos on the right hand side, fixed in main post. Must have been more tired last night when I posted than I thought. :/